# What is the file node.exe for?

Tags: node.js

I'm learning `Node.js` on a Windows environment. So far, I've been using the `Node.js command prompt` shortcut to run the commands.

But the Windows installer also creates a shortcut named simply `Node.js` that points to "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" and I'm not sure what is it for.

How can I use that program?

Comment: its nodejs command prompt...path already set to nodejs directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`node.exe` is full *Node.JS* executable, containing everything you need to run *Node.JS* applications on Windows.

You used the default installer, so it got installed to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe`. But you can also [download it separately](https://nodejs.org/download/) (**Windows Binary** option), and, for example, bundle it with your application package to simplify the installation on many machines.

There's no real need to use *"Node.js command prompt"* shortcut. You can launch *Node.JS* apps from regular Windows command line terminal, providing full path to `node.exe` executable (wherever it is actually located). An example:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe app.js
```

Comment: I still don't get what the node.exe UI is for since your example is also from command prompt which I guess would be the same as `node app.js` from command prompt but more typing.