# Run javascript file with GitBash from shortcut

Tags: javascript, git, git-bash, shortcut

So usually to start my js files I right click and "Git Bash Here" then I `node index.js`.

Now I'm wondering if that can be done through a shortcut instead.

I've looked around everywhere and no methods worked for me but I have managed `"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" -c` and it stays open.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update: There's no need to build Node.js

Since you already have Node.js installed, you can use the existing exe.

You can use [node.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359827/what-is-the-file-node-exe-for) instead of Git Bash for creating a shortcut.

Here are the steps I used (windows 10):

- Go to `C:/Program Files/nodejs`.
- Click `Create shortcut` for `node.exe`.
- Right click on the shortcut and open `Properties`
- Add the CLI args to the `Target` section. Before it was `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"`, but I changed it to `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" index.js`. Also change the `Start In` to be the working directory you want.

Comment: I realized that you don't need to build Node.js. I edited the answer to be much faster and simpler now.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to bash -c would be, [on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1413738/141):

```
 wsl.exe --exec node /mnt/c/MyFiles/index.js
```

That could also be setup as a shortcut.